# c# dynamic type correct usage

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic

I have 2 classes that share some properties

```
public class SportsUser
{
    public string errorCode { get; set; }
    //the sportsuser and SportsAdminUser is from a different database hence the long and int difference
    public long userId { get; set; }      
    ...        
}

public class SportsAdminUser
{
    public int userId { get; set; }
    public string errorCode { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

I also have an web api call that can be either passed a sessiontoken or a username and password which determines which class above I need to instantiate.

```
...
UserHandler userHandler = new UserHandler();                    
string errorCode = "";
int adminId = 0;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sessionToken))
{
      SportsUser sportsUser = new SportsUser();
      sportsUser = userHandler.CheckUpdateUserSessionToken(sessionToken);
      adminId = Convert.ToInt32(sportsUser.userId);
      errorCode = sportsUser.errorCode;
}
else
{
      SportsAdminUser sportsAdminUser = new sportsAdminUser();
      sportsAdminUser = userHandler.LoginUser(username, password);
      adminId = sportsAdminUser.userId;
      errorCode = sportsAdminUser.errorCode;
}

if (errorCode != "SESSION_INVALID" && errorCode != "INVALID_CREDENTIALS" && errorCode != "ACCOUNT_LOCKED")
{
Tuple<int, List<PunterTransaction>> resultTupe = businessLogic.GetCustomerTransactions(customerId, transactionsFromDateTimeTicks, transactionsToDateTimeTicks, adminId);
...
```

To make this cleaner i attempted to use dynamics as below but the userid property is a long vs int depending which class is used. How could i fix this and are dynamics right to use in this situation?Thanks.

```
UserHandler userHandler = new UserHandler();
dynamic tmp = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sessionToken))
{
     tmp = userHandler.CheckUpdateUserSessionToken(sessionToken);
}
else
{
     tmp = userHandler.LoginUser(username, password);
}

if (tmp.errorCode != "SESSION_INVALID" && tmp.errorCode != "INVALID_CREDENTIALS" && tmp.errorCode != "ACCOUNT_LOCKED")
{
    Tuple<int, List<CustomerTransaction>> resultTupe = businessLogic.GetCustomerTransactions(customerId, transactionsFromDateTimeTicks, transactionsToDateTimeTicks, tmp.bookmakerId);
```

Comment: Maybe I'm not properly understand the case, but it cannot just be a method that returns a generic type with constraint "struct"?

Comment: Ok using generics? could you explain to me a bit more how that would work?

Comment: Actually sorry. I misunderstood you. You mean the functions loginuser and checkupdateUserSessionToken can just return an errorcode and userid in a struct? That's not possible as in some cases i actually need access to other properties from the sportsuser and sportsadminuser objects. And so use the 2 functions in other places.

Comment: Only id property type is different? All others are same?

Comment: No, the sportsuser and sportsadminuser are completely different. The only props they share are errorcode and userid (although types are int vs long).

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I didn't undestand that properly.  I need to clarify something, what you want to achieve after initialization of `tmp` variable. You want to pass int or long or maybe the dynamic?.
I can't understand the case, but if you want use dynamic I suggest implement it like this.

I put some comments to better undestanding.

Create abstract class

```
public abstract class User
{
    public string ErrorCode { get; set; }
    public dynamic UserId { get; set; }
}
```

Classes `SportsUser` and `SportsAdminUser` will inherit `User`

```
public class SportsUser : User
{
}


public class SportsAdminUser : User 
{
}
```

Usage:

```
UserHandler userHandler = new UserHandler();
string sessionToken = "something";
string username = "user";
string password = "password";
User tmp;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sessionToken))
{
    tmp = userHandler.CheckUpdateUserSessionToken("sessionToken");
}
else
{
    tmp = userHandler.LoginUser(username, password);
}

//For testing type
var sportsUserTestType = userHandler.CheckUpdateUserSessionToken("sessionToken").UserId.GetType(); //int
var sportsAdminUserTestType = userHandler.LoginUser(username, password).UserId.GetType(); // long

if (tmp.ErrorCode != "SESSION_INVALID" && tmp.ErrorCode != "INVALID_CREDENTIALS" &&
            tmp.ErrorCode != "ACCOUNT_LOCKED")
 {
      Tuple<int, List<string>> resultTupe = businessLogic.GetCustomerTransactions(customerId, transactionsFromDateTimeTicks, transactionsToDateTimeTicks, tmp.UserId);

 }
```

My mock of UserHandler

```
public class UserHandler
{
    public SportsUser CheckUpdateUserSessionToken(string sessionToken)
    {
        //Do something

        return new SportsUser()
        {
            ErrorCode= "error1",
             UserId = 1 //int
        };
    }

    public SportsAdminUser LoginUser(string username, string password)
    {
        //Do something
        return new SportsAdminUser()
        {
            ErrorCode = "error2",
            UserId = 2L // long
        };
    }
}
```

Notice that `GetCustomerTransactions` method will still have to handle type dynamic (last argument)

Hope that helps